# Qml Video creation out of image stream from C++

Tags: c++, image, video-streaming, qml, qt5

After 10 days of endeavor, I'm back to the point of asking a fundamental question on my task.

I have a three-tier structure.

T1. A ROS project named 'MPC' which publishes a topic 'video_image' frames continuously (for example 30 frames of video image per second).

T2. C++ program developed as a Qt5.5 project-- kind of a middle worker.

T3. Image type object on a Qml UI(Qt5.5 Quick).

I want to show a video clip on T3 UI out of the frames from MPC(T1).
Up to this time, what I can surely do is to create QImages out of the frames from T1 and I can create a temporary image file (for example, currentFrame.jpg) on PWD.

What should I do to feed the frame stream as a source to UI video player(that is, up to now, I'm still thinking Image type as a video player UI candidate.)

Was I following a possible way to a solution? What would be a feasible way to create a video viewer feed from those picture frames stream?

Answer (score 7):

This is can be done by using the QQuickPaintedItem .

in the C++ Qt part you need to have a class which inherits QQuickPaintedItem :

*//imagewriter.h*

```
class imagewriter : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    imagewriter(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

    void paint(QPainter *painter);
    //the paint method is already implemented in QQuickPaintedItem
    //you just override it

    QImage image; //your image

};
```

*// imagewriter.cpp*

```
imagewriter::imagewriter(QQuickItem *parent): QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{

}

void imagewriter::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->drawImage(QPoint(0,0),this->image);
    //this will simply draw the image in your qml UI !
}
```

Now all you need is to register this object in order to be able to use it in your qml file :

*//in the main .cpp :*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<imagewriter>("mr.jb",1,0,"my_video_image");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

*// main.qml :*

```
import mr.jb 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


my_video_image {
            id : my_img_strm1
            anchors.centerin : parent
        }
}
```

The my_video_image object should be able to show your qimage, all you need to do is to keep updating that image to the last image you got from ROS stream, and each time you make that you invoke the predefined     **update();** method in order to automatically re-trigger the paint method  which is responsable of drawing your image in the qml world.
I suppose that you don't have problems with T1 part.

Receiving and building the image in T2 (the C++ class) can be done in many ways (QUdp for instance).

The last part (T3) is described in the above code.

Comment: Please tell me if you still not able to make it works